# Passing variable between activities using "."

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Suppose I declare and initialize the following variables in the main activity of my app:

```
public class MainActivity {
    int numberOfBricks = 23;
    int weightOfBrick = 13;
}
```

Suppose I then move to a second activity of the app, called SecondActivity, and I want to calculate the total weight of bricks. I would expect the procedure to simply be:

```
public class SecondActivity {
      int totalWeight = MainActivity.numberOfBricks * MainActivity.weightOfBrick;
}
```

Is that correct?

Comment: Pass the fields to next activity using extras. And use in next activity. That is best way.

Comment: Another note on this. As soon as the `SecondActivity` starts, the `MainActivity` instance is destroyed, so any values you set before no longer exist; you won't be able to access them unless they were sent in the intent.

Comment: @Nordii No it isn't.  As soon as SecondActivity exists the MainActivity instance is *eligible* to be destroyed.  It may not be.  Also, as he's using statics that wouldn't matter.  But its definitely NOT the way it should be done, Khermaj is right about using intents.

Answer (score 3):

This is not correct. `MainActivity.numberOfBricks` means that the variable is a static int that is common to all instances of the `MainActivity` class, when the one you want is actually for a single instance. You need to use an Intent to get to `SecondActivity` and with it send extras.

In `MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("numBricks", numberOfBricks);
intent.putExtra("weight", weightOfBrick);
startActivity(intent);
```

In `SecondActivity`'s `OnCreate()`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int numBricks = intent.getIntExtra("numBricks");
int weight = intent.getIntExtra("weight");
int totalWeight = numBricks * weight;
```

Using an extra puts the variable's data into the intent with a key that can be collected by the `SecondActivity` as long as it knows the key.

Comment: So if I declare static int numOfBricks and static int weightOfBrick in MainActivity, I can use them in SecondActivity as I initially stated?

Comment: Technically yes, but it would not be good practice to do it this way. I would definitely recommend the intent method.

Comment: I see. Does it also work if you use "numberOfBricks" in stead of "numBricks", and "weightOfBricks" in stead of "weight"?

Comment: Yes. I just wrote them that way to be concise. Name your variables and keys however you like as long as the names are consistent, and keys do not have to have the same names as variables.

Answer (score 3):

No. With the android app lifecycle, you start your second activity through an intent object.

With that intent object, you would do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

However, you can pass information to this intent, by calling putExtra on the intent object, like this:

```
intent.putExtra("NameForInformation", actualInformation)
```

e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("totalWeight", (numberOfBricks*weightOfBrick);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the onCreate of your second activity, you can do getIntent.getExtra("NameOfInformation") to retrieve the information

e.g.

```
int totalWeight = (int) getIntent.getExtra("totalWeight");
```